# Different colors between Monitor -> Display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, color

I just got home from buying my 2nd 4K monitor. This time, I bought a Samsung 4K monitor, but, I recently returned a 4K monitor from LG due to the same problem.

The problem is that the colors are noticeable different on the monitor respectively the Macbook Pro display.

Which leads me to my question, would the 4K LG UltraFine monitor solve this? If I purchased that monitor, could I be guaranteed that the screen would look the same across the monitor?

Here's a picture of my problem:
[image]

Comment: How exactly is the external display connected?

Answer (score 5):

Both the LG 4K and 5K look great next to 2015 / 2016 MacBook and MacBook Pro at the angle you have photographed. You could try to set a custom color calibration curve for both displays to bring them closer, but the color shift you have photographed is very large.

Also, be sure to set the contrast and brightness levels on the external display before you attempt software calibration. Lastly, let the display run for 30 minutes before attempting color calibration.